# Question about the kanji 兵

Tags: meaning, words, kanji

When I was sixteen I got my first tattoo and I choose this kanji " 兵 " because I saw that stands for warrior. A couple of years after, I saw that the kanji stands more for "soldiers" than "warrior" (meaning a brave man).

I don't know if the meaning is wrong or it can be disrespectful to the japanese culture.

Thank you for answering!

M.

Comment: According to the dictionary (weblio), when pronounced as 'tsuwamono' it would mean warrior in the sense you had hoped for, but when pronounced 'hei' it would mean a soldier of the lowest military rank. I guess the context would determine which, but I'm not a native and I don't know what would immediately come to a Japanese person's mind when they see this kanji.

Comment: nice question; it can also depend on where it is, if the character is by itself or in a phrase, the size, the style, if it's intended as a name, the reason for it, and if it indicates correct stroke order & count; some things don't translate very well,  and that concept may be one of those things: actually, it might be more respectful than another character mentioned, hei can be regarded very well, & it can be quiet and unassuming; tsuwamono(likely pronunciation from description in question) seems comparatively noninsulting  :)